# ¿Cómo ejecuto una lista de funciones?

Tags: python

Buenas ¿es posible hacer un bucle que recorra una lista de funciones y las ejecute en el main?

```
    
def a():
    print("func.A")
def b():
    print("func.B")
def c():
    print("func.C")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in ["a", "b", "c"]:
        i()
```

Comment: Si, la lista tiene que tiene que tener los nombre de las funciones (sin paréntesis), y luego llamas i().

Comment: Me sale un error

Comment: Las listas en Python pueden contener casi cualquier cosa. Si una función ya está definida, puede formar parte de una lista sin ningún problema: `for i in [a, b, c]:`

Comment: Si ahí lo corregí. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las funciones son objetos en Python. Las puedes manejar como variables usando solo el nombre, sin parentesis:

```
def a():
    print("func.A")
def b():
    print("func.B")
def c():
    print("func.C")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in [a, b, c]:
        i()
```

produce:

```
func.A
func.B
func.C
```

Si la función requiere parámetros, los pasas al momento de llamarla, como muestra esta segunda versión:

```
def a(par):
    print("func.A(", par, ")")
def b(par):
    print("func.B", par)
def c(par):
    print("func.C" + par)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in [a, b, c]:
        i("ejemplo")
```

produce:

```
func.A( ejemplo )
func.B ejemplo
func.C ejemplo
```